# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access with frame

Tags: javascript, iframe, spring-security, security

when i using Iframe and try to access different URL(same domain) into iframe, Am getting an error - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame

Error - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.example.com/1ad6af14-b2a5-4516-9a0a-ed1bfa3b7239.aspx from frame with URL http://www.example.com/Organizations/Dashboard.aspx?pagelink=hr. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

but i think it is not Cross-domain scripting problem because i am use same domain. Im not sure how to fix these issues, anyone willing to give any idea as to what may be the problem?

Comment: Your URLs resolve to 404 errors. Please don't use real sites for example URLs. `example.com` exists for that. (I suspect that you may have removed the problem when you changed the real URLs to fake URLs).